# Macports Imagemagick Install for PHP

Tags: macos, macports, imagemagick

I'm trying to install Imagick for PHP via Macports and the PECL extension, based on the guide [here](http://xentek.net/articles/442/installing-imagemagick-and-imagick-via-macports/):

```
sudo port install ImageMagick

sudo pecl install imagick
```

I entered the opt/local path and setup my php.ini file.

However when I start PHP I get the error:

`Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/imagick.so' - dlopen(/opt/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/imagick.so, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0`

I've searched for the imagick.so file and am unable to locate it anywhere.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

My bad: After selfupdating macports and reinstalling: I found the imagick.so in the location:

```
/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/imagick.so
```

So I created a symlink to this in my macports directory:

```
/opt/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626
```

Restarted apache and it seems to load now.